# Odoo 13 issue after transfered to new server

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-13

i transfered odoo 13 to an new server ubuntu but i get this issue

```
Error:
Odoo Server Error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 625, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)

  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 311, in _handle_exception
    raise pycompat.reraise(type(exception), exception, sys.exc_info()[2])

  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/tools/pycompat.py", line 14, in reraise
    raise value

  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 670, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)

  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 351, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)

  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/service/model.py", line 94, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)

  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 340, in checked_call
    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)

  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 916, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)

  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 516, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)

  File "/odoo/odoo-server/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1342, in call_kw
    return self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)

  File "/odoo/odoo-server/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1334, in _call_kw
    return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)

  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/api.py", line 383, in call_kw
    method = getattr(type(model), name)

AttributeError: type object 'res.users' has no attribute 'check_open_shift'
```

i copied old custom , enterprise and filestore folders to a new server

the second issue when access any module i get grayed screen and can't click any thing

i found 2 folders in custom folder , when i copied from old server to the new folder make server down
(hr_skill
vendor_custom)

Comment: Please post the error as a text, and not a screenshot.